# SQL Server filling gaps in time series

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, gaps-in-data

I'm having trouble with a request in SQL.

I have two tables, one representing a vector of dates and another timeseries of prices for different securities:

Dates:

| DateId | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 |

TimeSerie:

| SecurityId | DateId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.32 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.41 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.67 |

The timeserie may have gaps, for example in the above table the SecurityId=1 doesn't have any row at DateId=2 and SecurityId=2 doesn't have any rows at DateId=3.

I need to build a request that fill the gaps with the last previous value in the timeserie.
Resulting in having a value for all securities and all dates as follow:

| SecurityId | DateId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.32 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.41 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.67 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.67 |

I tried to start matching all dates with a right join

```
 SELECT  * from [TimeSerie] px RIGHT JOIN Dates dt on dt.DateId = px.Dateid
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as there is always a security for which the equality on DateId matches, so I don't get the TimeSeries rows having no values.

I'm working on SQL Server standard 2019 and I'am aiming to a solution based on a single query (avoiding procedures with temp tables or cursors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use CTEs and a windowed `COUNT` to put the data into groups and then get the `MAX` value of that group:

```sql
--Sample data
WITH Dates AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(date,'2021-01-01')),
                (2,CONVERT(date,'2021-01-02')),
                (3,CONVERT(date,'2021-01-03')))D(DateID,[Date])),
TimeSerie AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,1,0.25),
                (1,3,0.32),
                (2,1,0.41),
                (2,2,0.67))V(SecurityID,DateID,[Value])),
--Solution
DateSeries AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           D.DateID,
           D.[Date],
           TS.SecurityID
    FROM Dates D
         CROSS JOIN TimeSerie TS),
Groups AS(
    SELECT DS.SecurityID,
           DS.DateID,
           TS.[value],
           COUNT(TS.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY DS.SecurityID ORDER BY [Date]) AS Grp
    FROM DateSeries DS
         LEFT JOIN TimeSerie TS ON DS.SecurityID = TS.SecurityID
                               AND DS.DateID = TS.DateID)
SELECT G.SecurityID,
       G.DateID,
       MAX([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY G.SecurityID, G.Grp) AS [Value]
FROM Groups G;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join`:

```
select d.*, s.*, ts.value
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct securityid from timeseries) s left join
     (select ts.*,
             lead(ts.dateid) over (partition by securityid order by dateid) as next_dateid
      from timeseries ts
     ) ts
     on s.securityid = ts.securityid and
        d.dateid >= ts.dateid and
        (d.dateid < ts.next_dateid or ts.next_dateid is null);
```

This assumes that the `dateid`s are sequential which seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Hello Gordon, that's really great solution,  fast and simple. I didn't know the usage of lead, so I learned something. I've tried it and seems to work well even from a performance point of view. Also thanks to have edited the question before.